# O que significa "Você é o cara!"

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

O que significa **Você é o cara** ou **Ele é o cara**?

Quando algumas pessoas dizem "Nossa! Ele é o cara!", isso tem um sentido positivo ou negativo?  E o que significa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O sentido é bem positivo.  Significa que **ele tem qualidades que você muito admira**. Por exemplo:

- "Você quer saber se eu gosto dele?  Eu lhe respondo: **ele é o cara!**"
- "Eu acho que Roberto Carlos **é o cara**. Além de ser cantor, compositor, escritor, e um homem bom, também..."
- "Cite uma pessoa que você diria: esse aí é o cara?" "Hum, **meu pai é o cara**."

Observação: não é um termo de gênero neutro. Só conheço seu uso para indivíduos do sexo masculino. E é gíria.

Comment: Também é utilizado para indíviduos que demonstram grande competência ou são especialistas em determinados assuntos. "Tem dúvida em Química? Consulte Fulano, ele é o cara.", como "o cara que sabe muito" ou "o cara a quem você deve recorrer".